# reruning git status does not work properly

Tags: git, git-commit

I initialized the git on my myproject folder in desktop
and when I type git status command I get this

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        newfile.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

and after I rerun the git status it should pop up like this:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
```

but mine still says No commits yet and untracked file how should I fix this problem?
Thank you so much

Comment: `git status` does not change the state of the repo, only show the current state. To get what you expect, you have to `git add` the untracked files and then `git commit`.

Comment: Can you be more detailed? what do you do after the first git status? You should make sure to be in the right branch and then do `git add .` and  `git commit -m "Initial commit" `

Answer (score 1):

`Initial commit` and `No commits yet` represent the same thing from `git status`.  Old versions of Git say the former; new versions of Git say the latter.  The Git folks changed it when they found that newbies to Git found the `No commits yet` message more understandable.  Since yours says `No commits yet`, you just have a newer version of Git than whoever wrote your instructions.

---

An *untracked file* is one that is not in Git's *index*.  If you want that file to be in your next commit, you must use `git add` to *add* the file *to* Git's index.

The index, in Git, is a big and complicated thing, but there's an easy way to think about it for now, as a someone new to Git: Git's index holds your *proposed next commit*.  This index thing is so important that it has three names:

- the index (as I've been using above); or
- the *staging area:* this describes how you will *use* the index; or
- the *cache*.

This last name is pretty rare these days and mostly appears as a flag to various Git commands, e.g., `git diff --cached` or `git rm --cached`.  But all three names refer to the same thing, really.<sup>1</sup>

The thing to realize here is that once you make a commit, the files you've stored *in* that commit are *stored forever* as a *read-only archive*.<sup>2</sup>  So they become "safe": you can get them back, if you mess things up.  The *committed archive* version of those files literally can't be changed, not even by Git itself.  They're stored in a special, read-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format, that your computer itself can't read either: only Git can read them, and nothing can write them (other than the archive creation that happens only once per commit).

Because the committed files literally *can't be used*, you have to have Git *copy them out of a commit* before you can use the commit.  So that's what `git checkout` or the new (Git 2.23 or later) `git switch` does: it *copies a commit's files out*, so that you can see them and use them.

The copies you can see and use exist in what Git calls your *working tree*.  These files are ordinary, everyday files, that every program can read and write normally.  These are the files you use to get your work done.

The tricky bit—where Git's index comes in—is that, at all times, Git keeps a *third copy of every file*.  There's one copy in the commit, and the everyday one in your working tree.  But *in between these two*, Git has that extra *index* copy of each file.  This index "copy" is pre-de-duplicated, so that `git commit` will go fast—and won't actually take any *space* for files that are the same as old, already-committed files.  But each index copy of each file is *always present*.  It's there, ready to go, ready to be committed in the *next commit*.

This is what makes the index your *proposed next commit:* it holds a copy of every file, ready to be committed.  When you run `git commit`, Git doesn't look at your *working tree* files.  It looks at—and saves as a new archive/commit—the copies in Git's index.

Until you run `git add`, the index copy of any given file matches the committed copy you checked out.  If there was no committed copy checked out, the file just isn't even *in* the index yet.  So if you've created a new file in your working tree, and it isn't in Git's index, Git will list it as *untracked*.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>One Git command, `git apply`, makes an extra distinction between its `--index` and `--cached` flags, but for `git diff`, `--staged` and `--cached` mean exactly the same thing.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, they're only stored for as long as the commit itself exists, but usually that's "forever".  Don't worry about exceptions to this rule until later.

<sup>3</sup>Eventually, you'll find that a long list of untracked files is annoying.  There is a way to make `git status` shut up about some untracked files.  But leave that for later.